# rewrite the seqneighjoin function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the task to rewrite the seqneighjoin function in matlab by adding the frequency of all the sequences. After searching, I understand that this function returns a phylogenetic tree object obtained by seqences neighbor joinn method from the wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_joining
Now, I have the following two questions.
(1): what is the data structure of this phytree object obtained by this function? How to express it? For example, for the similar linkage function, it also returns a phylogenetic tree, and the data structure is very clear there, i.e., it is a matrix with three columns, where the i-th column indicates which nodes are combined and the corresponding distance when they are combined. Thanks very much for your time and attention.

(2): Based on wiki, how am I supposed to add frequency to the function seqneighjoin? I am totally confused.

Thanks so much for your time and attention. I truly appreciate that.

EDIT: the following is the code.

```
function z = seqneighjoin(D_all, freq)

   n = size (D_all, 2);
   m=(1+sqrt(8*n+1))/2;
   z=zeros(m-1,3);
   q=zeros(m,m);
   str = zeros (m,m);

   % initialize the distance matrix d
   d=ones(m,m);
   d(tril(d,-1)==1)=D_all;
   d(triu(d,1)==1)=D_all;
   d(eye(m,m)==1) = 1:m;  % the diagonal entries of the matrix d is the indices of the clusters

   % initialize the matrix str
   for r=1:m
       for c=1:m
           str(r,c)=freq(r)*freq(c)*d(r,c);
           str(c,r)=freq(r)*freq(c);
       end
   end




   % loop through for m-1 times to create the matrix z

   for k = 1:m-1

       % initialize (for the first time) or update (for all other times)
       % the matrix q

       colSum = sum(d, 1); 
       rowSum=sum(d,2);
       a=size(colSum, 2);
       colSumM=colSum(ones(a,1),:);
       rowSunM=rowSum(:,ones(1,a));
       q=(a-2)*d-colSumM-rowSumM;




       % find the minimum element in the matrix q
       u=min(q);
       v=min(u);
       [i,j]=find(q==v);
       r=i(1);
       c=j(1);

       % combine d(r,r) and d(c,c) to get a new node m+k

       z(k,:)=[d(r,r), d(c,c), v];

       % calculate the distance between the new node m+k and all other node
       % which are not m+k

       d(r,:) = (d(r,:) + d(c,:) - d(r,c) )/2;
       d(r,r) = m+k;
       d(c,:)=[]; d(:,c)=[];

   end
```

Here, D_all is the vector representation of a distance matrix returned by the seqpdist function in matlab, and freq is the vector indicating the frequency of all the sequences.

Comment: Can you add an example of some code you've tried so far? (edit your post to add an example)

Comment: @willpower2727, hope this is not a late reply. I was working on this for a while.